# QA platform requirements for KIK integration

Tags: kik

Is it fair to assume that if we tested on these platform, we've covered all QA requirements?

Our assumption is that testing on 7.0 is the same as 7.X, and similarly for Android, testing on an OS like Gingerbread would cover all 2.3 variants, and similarly Jelly Bean would cover all 4.1-4.3. Our assumption is that there isn't much difference btwn the variants.

Please advise on what good coverage is. Thanks.

iPhone 5C/7.0.4
iPhone 5S/8.0
iPhone 5/6.0
iPhone 5S/7.0.4
S2 Skyrocket/2.3.5/GINGERBREAD
LG Nexus 5/4.4.2/JELLYBEAN
Samsung Galaxy S4/4.2/JELLBEAN
HTC One X/4.0.3/ICE CREAM SANDWICH
Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini/4.1.1/JELLYBEAN
Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.7/3.2/HONEYCOMB

Answer (score 0):

Generally testing on any of the variants of the following will be sufficient for passing QA:

- iOS 4/5 (if you decided to include support for these)
- iOS 6
- iOS 7
- Android 2.2 (if you decide to include support for it)
- Android 2.3 (any one of 2.3.x will work)
- Android 4.0.3
- Android 4.3